# Why my domain gives me the old website while my IP address gives me the new one I deployed?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I recently bought a domain at AWS Route 53, and routed to my EC2 Instance with its elastic IP, record type A.

I made a kind of reverse proxy for manual blue-green deployment.(I don't yet know how to do that automatically) My nginx version is "nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)", and I'm using Django Rest Framework as backend and React JS as frontend. The below is codes which are seemed to be related with this issue.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
...Same as default...

http {
...Same as default...

   sendfile off;

...Same as default...

   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

...Same as default...
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
upstream main {
    server 192.168.0.1:8080; # This IP address is the gateway of docker network
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://main;

        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';

        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;

        proxy_cache off;
    }
}
```

PROJECT_FOLDER/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  backend-blue:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      args:
        DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS: stuff
        DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: stuff
        DJANGO_CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST: stuff
        BACKEND_ADMIN: stuff
        RDS_HOSTNAME: stuff
        RDS_PORT: stuff
        RDS_DB_NAME: stuff
        RDS_USERNAME: stuff
        RDS_PASSWORD: stuff
        S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID: stuff
        S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: stuff
        S3_BUCKET_NAME: stuff
        DEBUG: stuff
        EMAIL_HOST_USER: stuff
        EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: stuff
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    command: gunicorn backend.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend-blue:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    volumes:
      - build_folder:/frontend/build
  nginx-blue:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./webserver/nginx-proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - build_folder:/var/www/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend-blue
      - frontend-blue
volumes:
  build_folder:
```

PROJECT_FOLDER/webserver/nginx-proxy.conf

```
upstream api {
    server backend-blue:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen 8081;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api$request_uri;
    }

    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
      root /var/www/frontend;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Let's say the domain I bought is `example.com`. The problem is this. I deployed blue deployment with `docker-compose up --build -d` onto my EC2 Instance. And I changed IP gateway at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` with docker gateway created by new deployment(docker network inspect myproject_network). And I executed `sudo nginx -s reload`.

**But when I'm trying to access with `http://example.com`, it shows the old version of the website, while `http://<my-EC2-elastic-IP>` shows newly deployed website.**

Also I was not able to do the https protocol despite `mydomain.net` has a certificate.

I'm having pretty hard times with this issue

**Any help will be hugely appreciated**

Comment: Maybe you modified the DNS record but it is still being cached on your DNS resolver / browser and therefore directs you to the old site? DNS changes can take some time.

Comment: Do you have one nginx server running on the host and another one running in a docker container? Did you reload both the host and the container nginx service after changing the configuration files?

Comment: @rauberdaniel yep, you were right! It seemed dns changes took some time to take the effect of dns changes!

Comment: @Håken Lid yes I'm running nginx servers as you said. I didn't realized I should reload the nginx inside the container! Thanks for your comment!